# How can I send local database items over twilio?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ruby on rails beginner here. I've been trying to create a web application for my softball team that sends out a text message 24 hours before the game with a text message that says, "Are you going to be at the game?" The team than replies, "y or n" and it gets updated in the database.

I'm still learning, so the first thing I've been attempting to do is try and pull out information from the database about each game and send it over twilio.

```
def voice
  response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
    r.Say "Our next game will be at #{game.start_at}.", :voice => 'alice'
     #r.Play 'http://linode.rabasa.com/cantina.mp3'
  end

  render_twiml response
end
```

I pulled from the view/index.html.erb

```
#{game.start_at}
```

However, I get this error:

```
Game Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "games".* FROM "games" LIMIT 1                                                                                                                                                                
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 34ms                                                                                                                                                                               

NameError (undefined local variable or method `game' for #<TwilioController:0x007f7594530f00>):
```

I used this scaffolding command. And created a new game entry using the form.

```
rails generate scaffold games start_at:datetime ...
```

Could somebody point me in the right direction here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Views dont let you access local variables. Data has to be supplied from the controllers.

For example,

controllers/game_controller.rb

```
def something
  @my_variable = "Hello World"
  my_variable = "Something else"
end
```

views/game/something.html.erb

```
#{my_variable} <<- This gives error
#{@my_variable} <<- This is good!
```

To summarize,

`#{game.start_at} should have been #{@game.start_at}`

and **@game** be supplied from the view's controller action. In your case, that would be

```
def index
  @game = ...
end
```

of some controller.